# Lightbox effect in Parallax site (single page site)

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, lightbox, parallax

I have made a parallax website using the skrollr plugin.
I want to enable a ligtbox effect to display a gallery. (currently using the fancybox plugin)
What happens is that the fancybox overlay is applied to the whole body, which is about 15000px high and I have to manually scroll to the middle of the page to see the picture pop-up.  (i hope im making sense to people who have worked with skrollr)
I have tried rendering the fancybox on another div, with fixed position but it seems to screw it up.

Are there any work arounds to fixing this?
Some other lightbox plugin that will render on an fixed position overlay, stable regardless to scroll position or body width?(i dont need it to be extremely fancy)

Comment: well, normally fancybox will show in the middle of the viewport because regardless the overlay is appended to the body, it has a fixed position. that is the default behavior but in your case you may need to show the code you are using so we can check your particular settings.